# How to enable azure monitor in virtual machine using terraform?

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-monitoring

I am trying to enable azure monitor feature for my virtual machines which checks for health and performance of the VM using terraform but I am not able to find the right documentation for the same. Can you help me for the same because I want detailed monitoring for azure.

This is what I want to automate using terraform, enable health & performance using Azure Monitor for VM's

Here is the Azure Monitor for VM Screenshot 
https://ibb.co/JmzfNZN

Answer (score 0):

Enable Azure Monitor for VMs service is still in preview mode and is not available as a module in Terraform.

To raise a new feature request in Terraform for Azure, please use the below link:

https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/new?template=enhancement.md